# Property text-overflow: ellipsis not working

Tags: css

I have a table where th `<td>` are styled as follows.

```
table.tvTable td{
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap; // with this line i get one erally wide row
  padding: 3px;
}
```

Individually, they are styles with `width` (both in px, % and *). I also tried to set the width of the whole table too (which don't want to do beccause i want one of the columns to utilize maximum width available on the screen).

However, no clipping occures, let alone ellipsisation. I'm on Ch and FF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HLhSw/2/) of how I got it working. You indeed have to use `table-layout: fixed` as was mentioned. Setting the width of the `td` via CSS seems to work, as well, without having to specify it in the HTML.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Ah, there it was! `table-layout: fixed` is supposed to be on the table, not the individual `<td>`. I have a remark, though. In your example, you used `-webkit-text-overflow: ellipsis;` but accoring to [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-overflow), it's not needed. Old dogs new tricks or was it intentional?

Comment: The former, I suppose! Apparently that vendor prefix isn't needed as Chrome and Safari appear to support the property! Good catch :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have to use `table-layout: fixed;` AND set your table a width.

Comment: Oh, that's a gotcha... I'm going to try to put the width to 90% or something like and it's best for the browser it'll work or i'm quitting internet! EDIT: I did table.tvTable{
 width: 90%;
}

table.tvTable tr{
 table-layout: fixed;
 height: 20px;
} but it still doesn't work. Anything else i might be missing?

Comment: I ment this:    table.tvTable td{
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
 padding: 3px;
 table-layout: fixed;
 font: 14px Courier;
}

Comment: table-layout must be applied on table, not td